# Travelling Salesman problem using Guided Local Search

Tags: optimization, heuristics, integer-programming, traveling-salesman

I am doing Week_4 of https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization/
stuck in solving TSP.
As there are a lot of methods to solve this problem, I am currently coding
Guided Local Search as described [here](http://csp.bracil.net/papers/VTA-GLS-Handbook2010.pdf).
This basically penalizes the longest edge and repeatedly searches that neighborhood until no improvement found. To search the neighborhood faster, it uses Fast Local search which basically marks a vertex inactive if no improving (2-Opt) moves are found.

My problem is that I do not see any improvement after the first Fast Local Search(FLS).
Any insights on this?

Also, what is the suggested method to solve TSP in order to ease?
Like I know these are methods
- Simulated Annealing with re-heat.
- Mixed Integer Programming(MIP) with Gomory Cut.
- LK(Lein-Kerninghan), LKH, ILKH heuristics
- GLS+FLS (I find this easy to start with)
- Hybrid approaches like MIP + SA.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. People have written surveys on practical approaches to TSP. Perhaps you could take a look at some of them.

Comment: Thanks, should I try 3-opt, when 2  opt stuck in local minima